# How to determine the maximum,minimum and average values of the matrix

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I need to create a matrix, where the user can input his values and determine the maximum value of the matrix, the minimum value and the average value of all matrix's data

I created the matrix, where I can input my own values and I tried to write which could determine the maximum and minimum value. However, after several checks, I understood, that my piece of code, which determines max and min values, doesn't work.

```
line = int(input('Enter the amount of lines:'))
columns = int(input('Enter the amount of columns:'))

matrix = []
for i in range(0, columns):
    matrix.append([])

for i in range(0, line):
    for j in range(0, columns):
        matrix[i].append(j)
        matrix[i][j] = 0


for i in range(0, line):
    for j in range(0,columns):
        matrix[i][j] = int(input('Enter the value:'))
        avg = matrix

for i in range(0, line):
    for j in range(0, columns):
        max_val = matrix[j]
        min_val = matrix[j]
        for j in range(0, len(matrix[j]), 1):
            max_val = max(max_val, matrix[j])
            min_val = min(min_val, matrix[j])

maxVal = max_val[0]
minVal = min_val[0]
for i in range(0, len(max_val), 1):
    maxVal = max(maxVal, max_val[i])
    minVal = min(minVal, min_val[i])

print(matrix)
print('The maximum value is ' + str(maxVal))
print('The minimum value is ' + str(minVal))
```

I excepted the result, which will print me the matrix, maximum value, minimum value and average value

Comment: I'd recommend using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/)

Comment: But can I do without numpy? @norok2

Comment: Of course you can, but why would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it with Python `list`s is this:

(I'll just do `find_min()`, as `find_max()` and `compute_mean()` would be pretty much the same.)

```
import random


def gen_random_matrix(rows, cols, min_val=1, max_val=100):
    return [
        [random.randint(min_val, max_val) for j in range(cols)]
        for i in range(rows)]


def find_min(matrix):
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])
    min_i, min_j = 0, 0
    min_val = matrix[min_i][min_j]
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
             if matrix[i][j] < min_val:
                 min_i = i
                 min_j = j
                 min_val = matrix[i][j]
    return min_val, min_i, min_j


random.seed(0)

matrix = gen_random_matrix(3, 4)

print(matrix)
# [[50, 98, 54, 6], [34, 66, 63, 52], [39, 62, 46, 75]]

print(find_min(matrix))
# (6, 0, 3)
```